# Fastest way to filter a data.frame list column contents in R / Rcpp

Tags: r, performance, data.table, dplyr, rcpp

I have a data.frame:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, vars = list("a", c("a", "b", "c"), c("b", 
"c"))), .Names = c("id", "vars"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

with a list column (each with a character vector):

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ id  : int  1 2 3
     $ vars:List of 3
      ..$ : chr "a"
      ..$ : chr  "a" "b" "c"
      ..$ : chr  "b" "c"
```

I want to filter the data.frame according to `setdiff(vars,remove_this)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
res <- df %>% mutate(vars = lapply(df$vars, setdiff, "a"))
```

which gets me this:

```
   > res
      id vars
    1  1     
    2  2 b, c
    3  3 b, c
```

But to get drop the `character(0)` vars I have to do something like:

```
res %>% unnest(vars) # and then do the equivalent of nest(vars) again after...
```

#### Actual datasets:

- 560K rows and 3800K rows that also have 10 more columns (to carry along).

(this is quite slow, which leads to question...)

### What is the Fastest way to do this in `R`?

- Is there a `dplyr`/ `data.table`/ other faster method?
- How to do this with `Rcpp`?

#### UPDATE/EXTENSION:

- can the column modification be done in place rather then by copying the `lapply(vars,setdiff(...` result?
- what's the most efficient way to filter out for `vars == character(0)` if it *must* be a seperate step.

Comment: By "filter" you seem to mean drop rows for which, after the `setdiff`, you end up with `character(0)`... which only happens if the list is a singleton `list("a")`. Is that right? Anyway, to talk about speed, you'll probably need to produce some example data.

Comment: @Frank yes. Generally I want to drop rows where the `setdiff` evaluates to `character(0)`. Having control over whether or not to drop would be handy.

Comment: I think only the first @ name gets pinged. eddi means that the `data.table` way does modify in place. I think best practice is not to use a list column if the contents are analysis-intensive. Instead, create dummies or a categorical/string variable for subsets (as in my answer). [cont...]

Comment: It's not as logically elegant as subsetting the list column and filtering, but you can keep the latter around as well, for aesthetics ... just not using it for costly or repeated analytical operations. As far as automagic goes, keying on the categorical variable *does* make subsetting fairly instant (at least in the example data in my answer) -- that's `data.table` showing its strength.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting aside any algorithmic improvements, the analogous `data.table` solution is automatically going to be faster because you won't have to copy the entire thing just to add a column:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df)  # or use setDT to convert in place

dt[, newcol := lapply(vars, setdiff, 'a')][sapply(newcol, length) != 0]
#   id  vars newcol
#1:  2 a,b,c    b,c
#2:  3   b,c    b,c
```

You can also delete the original column (with basically 0 cost), by adding `[, vars := NULL]` at the end). Or you can simply overwrite the initial column if you don't need that info, i.e. `dt[, vars := lapply(vars, setdiff, 'a')]`.

---

Now as far as algorithmic improvements go, assuming your `id` values are unique for each `vars` (and if not, add a new unique identifier), I think this is much faster and automatically takes care of the filtering:

```
dt[, unlist(vars), by = id][!V1 %in% 'a', .(vars = list(V1)), by = id]
#   id vars
#1:  2  b,c
#2:  3  b,c
```

To carry along the other columns, I think it's easiest to simply merge back:

```
dt[, othercol := 5:7]

# notice the keyby
dt[, unlist(vars), by = id][!V1 %in% 'a', .(vars = list(V1)), keyby = id][dt, nomatch = 0]
#   id vars i.vars othercol
#1:  2  b,c  a,b,c        6
#2:  3  b,c    b,c        7
```

Comment: @Frank in simple cases, yes, but if OP is taking out several letters at a time, you'd need to check for all of the combinations

Comment: @Frank don't forget that OP mentioned that they have a bunch of extra columns to carry around

Comment: I think that using `rowwise()` + `do()` I should only keep `id` and `newcol` and then `left_join()` with `id` on the original dataframe, right ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré If `id` is the row number (as it seems), it's much faster to simply subset with it than to join on it. I don't know if that can be done in a single piped expression, though.

Comment: @eddi this is a good start but questions:  is there any way `lapply(vars, setdiff, 'a')` could be done in place instead of copying? And: `sapply(newcol, length) != 0`  is this best practise for these things? there's isn't a more automagic data.table way of doing this? @Frank @StevenBeaupré

Comment: i've updated my question to see if there's more out of each piece -- thanks so much for taking the time and effort! @Frank

Comment: @hannahheres you can overwrite `vars`, i.e. `vars := lapply(...)`, instead of creating a new column and I can't really think of a different way to filter out the `character(0)` rows

Comment: @hannahheres I added a different way of doing it, avoiding `setdiff` which I think is pretty slow. @Frank would appreciate it if you could add to benchmarks.

Comment: Okay, your approach is 5x as fast as mine. I also explored a wider set of simulation parameters and found that mine has a huge slowdown when the set of `baduns` (elements to be excluded) is "very large" (over 20), at which point it is slower than the OP's. It's also a lot slower when working with non-characters. If we can ever use `by=` with a list column so that my `paste0` can go per-group instead of per-row, my method might catch up. The point about using a key if doing this many times still holds. I guess each is useful for a different context. Yours is by far the fastest one-off.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another way:

```
# prep
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[,vstr:=paste0(sort(unlist(vars)),collapse="_"),by=1:nrow(DT)]
setkey(DT,vstr)

get_badkeys <- function(x) 
  unlist(sapply(1:length(x),function(n) combn(sort(x),n,paste0,collapse="_")))

# choose values to exclude
baduns  <- c("a","b")

# subset
DT[!J(get_badkeys(baduns))]
```

This is fairly fast, but it takes up your `key`.

---

**Benchmarks.** Here's a made-up example:

*Candidates:*

```
hannahh <- function(df,baduns){
    df %>% 
        mutate(vars = lapply(.$vars, setdiff, baduns)) %>% 
        filter(!!sapply(vars,length))
}
eddi    <- function(df,baduns){
        dt = as.data.table(df)
        dt[, 
          unlist(vars)
        , by = id][!V1 %in% baduns, 
          .(vars = list(V1))
        , keyby = id][dt, nomatch = 0]
}   
stevenb <- function(df,baduns){
    df %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      do(id = .$id, vars = .$vars, newcol = setdiff(.$vars, baduns)) %>%
      mutate(length = length(newcol)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      filter(length > 0)
}
frank   <- function(df,baduns){
    DT <- data.table(df)
    DT[,vstr:=paste0(sort(unlist(vars)),collapse="_"),by=1:nrow(DT)]
    setkey(DT,vstr)
    DT[!J(get_badkeys(baduns))]
}
```

*Simulation:*

```
nvals  <- 4
nbads  <- 2
maxlen <- 4

nobs   <- 1e4

exdf   <- data.table(
  id=1:nobs,
  vars=replicate(nobs,list(sample(valset,sample(maxlen,1))))
)
setDF(exdf)
baduns <- valset[1:nbads]
```

*Results:*

```
system.time(frank_res   <- frank(exdf,baduns))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.24    0.00    0.28 
system.time(hannahh_res <- hannahh(exdf,baduns))
#   0.42    0.00    0.42
system.time(eddi_res    <- eddi(exdf,baduns))
#   0.05    0.00    0.04
system.time(stevenb_res <- stevenb(exdf,baduns))
#   36.27   55.36   93.98
```

*Checks:*

```
identical(sort(frank_res$id),eddi_res$id) # TRUE
identical(unlist(stevenb_res$id),eddi_res$id) # TRUE
identical(unlist(hannahh_res$id),eddi_res$id) # TRUE
```

*Discussion:*

For `eddi()` and `hannahh()`, the results scarcely change with `nvals`, `nbads` and `maxlen`. In contrast, when `baduns` goes over 20, `frank()` becomes incredibly slow (like 20+ sec); it also scales up with `nbads` and `maxlen` a little worse than the other two.

Scaling up `nobs`, `eddi()`'s lead over `hannahh()` stays the same, at about 10x. Against `frank()`, it sometimes shrinks and sometimes stays the same. In the best `nobs = 1e5` case for `frank()`, `eddi()` is still 3x faster.

If we switch from a `valset` of characters to something that `frank()` must coerce to a character for its by-row `paste0` operation, both `eddi()` and `hannahh()` beat it as `nobs` grows.

---

**Benchmarks for doing this repeatedly.** This is probably obvious, but if you have to do this "many" times (...how many is hard to say), it's better to create the key column than to go through the subsetting for each set of `baduns`. In the simulation above, `eddi()` is about 5x as fast as `frank()`, so I'd go for the latter if I was doing this subsetting 10+ times.

```
maxbadlen    <- 2
set_o_baduns <- replicate(10,sample(valset,size=sample(maxbadlen,1)))

system.time({
    DT <- data.table(exdf)
    DT[,vstr:=paste0(sort(unlist(vars)),collapse="_"),by=1:nrow(DT)]
    setkey(DT,vstr)

    for (i in 1:10) DT[!J(get_badkeys(set_o_baduns[[i]]))]
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.29    0.00    0.29

system.time({
    dt = as.data.table(exdf)
    for (i in 1:10) dt[, 
      unlist(vars), by = id][!V1 %in% set_o_baduns[[i]],
      .(vars = list(V1)), keyby = id][dt, nomatch = 0]
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.39    0.00    0.39

system.time({
    for (i in 1:10) hannahh(exdf,set_o_baduns[[i]])
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 4.10    0.00    4.13
```

So, as expected, `frank()` takes very little time for additional evaluations, while `eddi()` and `hannahh()` grow linearly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  do(id = .$id, vars = .$vars, newcol = setdiff(.$vars, "a")) %>%
  mutate(length = length(newcol)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Which gives:

```
#  id    vars newcol length
#1  1       a             0
#2  2 a, b, c   b, c      2
#3  3    b, c   b, c      2
```

You could then filter on `length > 0` to keep only non-empty `newcol`

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  do(id = .$id, vars = .$vars, newcol = setdiff(.$vars, "a")) %>%
  mutate(length = length(newcol)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(length > 0)
```

Which gives:

```
#  id    vars newcol length
#1  2 a, b, c   b, c      2
#2  3    b, c   b, c      2
```

**Note**: As mentioned by @Arun in the comments, this approach is quite slow. You are better off with the `data.table` solutions.

Comment: `do()` is quite slow AFAICT. This takes 90s (vs 2.3s for eddi's) on 100,000 rows.. Also, `length = length(vars)` is not right, I think.

Comment: @Arun I agree that `do()` is quite slow. But AFAIK, `rowwise()` + `do()` is the most `dplyr`-esque way to apply a function to each row.  `length` is just a variable storing the length of the list created

Comment: `length()` inside mutate is equal to `sapply(list, length)`??

Comment: @Arun Yes it is retained. Anyways, this solution is so slow compared to anything in `data.table` it's probably not even worth mentioning :/

Comment: Does it mean that `filter()` is also being run for each row separately? How do you know which operation has group retained?

Comment: @Arun Here I think `filter()` strips the `rowwise()` nature of the dataframe.