# R - how to remove an element from a list in a datatable

Tags: r, list, data.table

I have a basic question. I have a table (data.table) like the following:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(a = c(3,4,4,7,7,8), b = list(c(3,4,7,8,9)))  

   a |     b
1: 3 | 3,4,7,8,9
2: 4 | 3,4,7,8,9
3: 4 | 3,4,7,8,9
4: 7 | 3,4,7,8,9
5: 7 | 3,4,7,8,9
6: 8 | 3,4,7,8,9
```

I need to remove the number in column 'a' from the 'b' column. Column 'b' elements are lists.
So the result should be something like the following.

```
   a |    b      |   c
1: 3 | 3,4,7,8,9 | 4,7,8,9
2: 4 | 3,4,7,8,9 | 3,7,8,9
3: 4 | 3,4,7,8,9 | 3,7,8,9
4: 7 | 3,4,7,8,9 | 3,4,8,9
5: 7 | 3,4,7,8,9 | 3,4,8,9
6: 8 | 3,4,7,8,9 | 3,4,7,9
```

How can I do this? preferably by data.table
Thanks

Comment: `DT[, .(Map(setdiff, b, a))]` does it, but will probably be very slow, like most operations with list columns. Also, it does it for this example, but if you have duplicated values in b, this will remove them.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30177951/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! It was very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is `unlist`

```
dt[,  c:= .(list(unlist(b)[!unlist(b) %in% a])), 1:nrow(dt)][]
#   a         b       c
#1: 3 3,4,7,8,9 4,7,8,9
#2: 4 3,4,7,8,9 3,7,8,9
#3: 4 3,4,7,8,9 3,7,8,9
#4: 7 3,4,7,8,9 3,4,8,9
#5: 7 3,4,7,8,9 3,4,8,9
#6: 8 3,4,7,8,9 3,4,7,9
```