# Match On (of Filter By) Column Contents in List

Tags: r, join, filter, dplyr

First, here's my data:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(ID = c("22738", "22738", "25461", "25461", "21353", "22867", "22867", "23396", "24572", "25030", "25030", "25740", "25740"),IDS_VERIFIED = list(c("22540", "22867"), c("21648", "22738"), c("25030", "25293"), c("23075", "24127", "25461"), "21353", c("22540", "22867"), c("21648", "22738"), "23396", c("24545", "24572"), c("25030", "25293"), c("23075", "24127", "25461"), "25740", character(0)))

# A tibble: 13 x 2
      ID IDS_VERIFIED
   <chr>       <list>
 1 22738    <chr [2]>
 2 22738    <chr [2]>
 3 25461    <chr [2]>
 4 25461    <chr [3]>
 5 21353    <chr [1]>
 6 22867    <chr [2]>
 7 22867    <chr [2]>
 8 23396    <chr [1]>
 9 24572    <chr [2]>
10 25030    <chr [2]>
11 25030    <chr [3]>
12 25740    <chr [1]>
13 25740    <chr [0]>
```

### What I Need

What I need is simple. I need to filter by `df$ID %in% df$IDS_VERIFIED`, preferably in dplyr-friendly syntax.

In other words, identify - for each row - if ID is in the corresponding list of IDS_VERIFIED (for that row).

### What I've Tried

Tried the obvious:

```
filter(ID %in% IDS_VERIFIED)
```

Also tried the idiotic:

```
filter(ID %in% unlist(IDS_VERIFIED)
```

Finally, I tried going back to the basics that I still haven't learned, as I suspect the answer lies in `lapply`. But it's going to take me a while to get my head around how to use it, and I need to solve the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If you load the entire tidyverse plus magrittr, there's `df %>% filter(map2_lgl(ID, IDS_VERIFIED, is_in))`... seems silly to me, though.

Comment: silly why? i already have magrittr installed, i've just never delved into it. should i try, or would i see if there's a better solution? thanks, Frank.

Comment: I mean silly because I'm introducing extra 'verse verbs when functionally identical base R ones already exist, so you can do... `df %>% filter(mapply(\`%in%\`, ID, IDS_VERIFIED))`

Comment: Thanks! Tried the magrittr one and it does exactly what I need. I'll try the base R way too, because I learn that way. (I'm an R novice, if it's not obvious.)

Comment: btw, Frank, if you post your solution as an answer, I can check it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just dplyr, there's

```
df %>% filter(mapply(`%in%`, ID, IDS_VERIFIED))
```

If you are learning "tidyverse"-flavored R, there's also

```
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
df %>% filter(map2_lgl(ID, IDS_VERIFIED, is_in))
```

By the way, analysis on list columns can be slow. ([An example here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30177951/))

Comment: Thanks again, Frank. Actually, I generated the list column with str_extract_all & a regex match function. Is there a better way for me to do the whole thing? Should I add an example of what I'm talking about, or is it clear?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure. I usually manage to avoid analysis on list columns but perhaps your use-case is different. If you want to post about it, I'd suggest a new question or maybe https://community.rstudio.com/ (which is more open to "best practices" questions than Stack Overflow is). I don't know really know stringr functions myself.